# Polymer 2.0 paper-listbox selected event

Tags: polymer

I seem to have misplaced several dozen IQ points....

I'm trying to catch an iron-items-changed event from a paper-dropdown-menu from the host. For the life of me I can't figure out (or find an example of) the syntax.

```
<paper-listbox .... onclick="doSomething()">
```

works fine. But oniron-items-changed doesn't. Nor does on-iron-items-changed. Nor onIronItemsChanged. Or any other variation of the event name that I can think of.

Anyway, can someone help? Please???

UPDATE:
I'm beginning to think the problem is that it's an event bubbling issue. I tried moving the attribute up a level to the paper-dropdown-menu element, but that didn't help. Any ideas? Here's the HTML that's being delivered to the browser:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/app-layout/app-scroll-effects/effects/waterfall.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-header/app-header.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">

    <style>
       #pageContent {
           margin: 20px;
       }
    </style>
</head> 

<body unresolved>
    <app-header-layout>
        <app-header slot="header" fixed condenses shadow effects="waterfall">
            <app-toolbar>
                <div main-title>FTI Calculation Editor</div>
            </app-toolbar>
        </app-header>
        <div id="pageContent">
          <paper-dropdown-menu label="Master" id="master" on-selected-item-changed="doSomething" >
              <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" >
                      <paper-item>Test One</paper-item>
                      <paper-item>Test Three</paper-item>
                      <paper-item>Test Two</paper-item>
              </paper-listbox>
          </paper-dropdown-menu>

          <p></p>

          <paper-dropdown-menu label="Child" id="child">
              <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content">
                      <paper-item>C 1-1</paper-item>
                      <paper-item>C 1-2</paper-item>
                      <paper-item>C 1-3</paper-item>
                      <paper-item>C 2</paper-item>
                      <paper-item>C 3-1</paper-item>
                      <paper-item>C 3-3</paper-item>
                      <paper-item>C 3-4</paper-item>
                      <paper-item>C-3-2</paper-item>
              </paper-listbox>
          </paper-dropdown-menu>
        </div>
    </app-header-layout>

    <script>
        function doSomething(e) {
            alert("got here");
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Probably obvious, but what I'm ultimately trying to achieve is to filter the second dropdown based on the selection in the first. If somebody knows a better/easier way to achieve that, I'd be delighted to know....

Answer (score 0):

Just look into documentation. It points you to a good path. As you can see in [documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-listbox/elements/paper-listbox#event-iron-items-changed), there is `-on-iron-items-changed` so problem must be somewhere else.

You can't call functions with `()` at the end. You need to point to some function and not actually call it. So rewrite your code to:

```
<paper-listbox .... on-iron-items-changed="doSomething">
```

Comment: Sorry, the parens were a typo. But on-iron-items-changed doesn't trigger the method. That's kind of my point. I thought it should, but when it didn't, I thought maybe there was something going on with name mapping that I'd missed.

Answer (score 0):

The way you get the event with `onclick="domsomething()"` does something because you are not using the actual Polymer syntax, that's the "old" HTML way to catch the click even. But you might not want that, at least because it's not the best when it comes to touch devices support (there's on-tap for tat).

But in your case, now, the other answer was pretty close. First of all you don't need to call a function, you need to pass a name that can be used by the paper-listbox element as a callback.

The only difference is that you are not interested in the event triggered when the items are changed. That would be when the list changes. I am guessing that you are interested in the event triggered when the selected one changes. So on that page you can see that there's an event called `selected-item-changed`. That would mean that that you can use the `on-selected-item-changed` attribute to define a callback for that event.

So please try:

```
<paper-listbox .... on-iron-items-changed="doSomething">
```

You `doSomething` method will get one parameter, the event object.